# How can I get the key Values in a JSON array in ruby?

Tags: ruby, json

I have the following *JSON*-Structure:

```
{ "A" : "1", "B" : "2", "RandomOtherName" : "54738" }
```

How can I extract the key values (`"A"`, `"B"`, `"RandomOtherName"`,...) in ruby (Preferably in to an array)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
require 'json'
data = '{ "A" : "1", "B" : "2", "RandomOtherName" : "54738" }'
JSON.parse(data).keys # => ["A", "B", "RandomOtherName"]
```