# Parse JSON where object is variable

Tags: json, ruby

I get the following JSON response for Alpha vantage Stock API:

```
    "Time Series (Daily)": {
        "2018-07-09": {
            "1. open": "142.6000",
             ...
        },
```

I get different dates depending on the location of the stock exchange. On some, it might say `"2018-07-09"`, and on others `"2018-07-10"`.

Is there a way to reach the attributes of an object without typing the object, something along the lines of:

```
["Time Series (Daily)"]["first_child"]["1. open"]
```

Using:

```
["Time Series (Daily)"][0]["1. open"]
```

doesn't work.

Comment: This seems relevant. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983267/ Worth mentioning that this will be somewhat performance-taxing if your object is very large/has many properties.

Comment: Thanks for that, I've looked at that question, however it doesn't help me that much as I'm parsing it with rails. Using the index of [0], returns nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ruby_hash["Time Series (Daily)"].values.first["1. open"]
```

Comment: Syntax error?

@result = @parse_result["Time Series (Daily)"]values.first["1. open"]

Comment: @Crashtor Sorry, missed a period before `values`. Fixed.

Comment: This answer solves this specific case, but it does not handle retrieving properties other than the first one of the object.

Answer (score 1):

Adapted from [How can I get the key Values in a JSON array in ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32759742/5352336)

```
require 'json'
myData = JSON.parse('{"A": {"B": {"C": {"D": "open sesame"}}}}')

def getProperty(index, parsedData)
  return parsedData[parsedData.keys[index]]
end  

myDataFirstProperty = getProperty(0, myData) # => {"B"=>{"C"=>{"D"=>"open sesame"}}}

evenDeeper = getProperty(0, myDataFirstProperty) # => {"C"=>{"D"=>"open sesame"}}
```

This answer can also get the Nth property of the JSON, unlike the accepted answer which can only get the first.

Comment: This only gets me to where I would before, ( ["2018-07-09"] ) - I need to go 1 step down. I feel like such a noob.

Comment: Use `keys` again on the next object within json.  https://repl.it/repls/SophisticatedFavorableRobodoc. Worth noting that my answer can get properties other than the first property, which cannot be done with the accepted answer.